# IIS terminates Worker Process after every request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an ASP.Net Application in framework 4.5.1.
After every call the IIS worker process is terminated and I don't know why.
IIS logs the following error message:

> A process serving application pool 'WebAPI' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '18840'. The data field contains the error number.

That's the source of my ApiController.

```
public class MyController : ApiController {
    public HttpResponseMessage GetInfo(string param, string param2) {

        try {
            string response = Foo(param,param2);

            return new HttpResponseMessage() {
                Content = new StringContent(
                    response,
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "text/html"
                    )
            };
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return new HttpResponseMessage() {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                Content = new StringContent(
                    ex.Message + ":" + ex.StackTrace,
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "text/html"
                    )
            };
        } 
    }
}
```

Does anyone has a clue why it terminates after every request?

thanks

**edit: Windows Event Log** + the request was completed successfully but still terminates afterwards

```
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/med

Process ID: 7156

Exception: System.Runtime.FatalException

Message: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.

StackTrace:    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.FinishRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsyncCompleted(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException

Message: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.

StackTrace:    at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ThreadBehavior.BindCore(MessageRpc& rpc, Boolean startOperation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
```

Comment: I would take a look at Windows Event Log to see if there is more information about the error..

Comment: I added the corresponding windos event log entry